# 240 bit radar word

Tags: binary, serial-port, arduino, ls, octal

I Have a project using a `240 bit` Octal data format that will be coming in the serial port of `Arduino uno` at 2.4K RS232 converted to TTL.

The `240 bits` along with other things has range, azimuth and elevation words, which is what I need to display.

The frame starts with a frame sync code wich is an alternating binary 7 bit code which is:
 `1110010` for frame 1 and
`0001101` for frame 2 and so on.

I was thinking that I might use something like `val = serial.read` command like

```
if (val = 1110010 or 0001101) { data++val; }`
```

that will let me validate the start of my sting.

The rest of the `240 bit` octal frame (all numbers) can be serial read to a string of which only parts will be needed to be printed to the screen.

Past the frame sync, all octal data is serial with no Nulls or delimiters so I am thinking

```
printf("%.Xs",stringname[xx]);
```

will let me off set the characters as needed so they can be parsed out.

How do I tell the program that the frame `sync` its looking for is `binary` or that the data that needs to go into the string is `octal`, or that it may need to be converted to be read on the screen?

Comment: Are you sure this is coming in as ASYNC data (which is what the Serial object in Arduino understands)?  It sounds like it is a SYNCHRONOUS serial stream -- which is very different.  Usually with synchronous one of the signal lines will be called "clock" or "clk".  This is how the data is captured, and sometimes a baud rate will not be specified, or it will be unusual.

Comment: What do you mean by "octal data format"? What does the data received look like? Can you show an example input stream?

Comment: stringname[xx] is a char, not a string.  You'll at least need &stringname[xx].  It also has to be zero-terminated.

Comment: *"serial port...at 2.4K RS232 converted to TTL."* -- RS232 levels are always converted to TTL for the UART.  So the baud rate is 2400.  What are the other serial port attributes, e.g. char length, parity and stop bits?  Does a sync char of 7 bits imply a 7-bit char length?  240 bits could be (34+1)*7 or 30*8; that is, your `read()` could return 34+1 or 30 bytes depending on how you setup the serial port char size.  Or is this truly a bit string?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t state that earlier, yes this is truly a bit string that is originally a RS232 2.4K synchronous bit string of 240 bits.  I have converted the sync string to async for the Arduino serial interface using a MAS7838 chip .  The Original sync frame is a bit string.  The first 7 bits are just as I have stated for the frame  or start of string .  the rest of the 233 bit string has fields like bits 45-57 might be for elevation and bits 78-80 might be range.   This is all represented in octal.  I will try to get you a copy of the entire frame.

Comment: Octal, binary or hexadecimal -- essentially they are the same bit patterns, but the representation uses different bit groupings.  The "octal" you mention means a grouping of 3 bits at a time.  These bits are going to be stored in a byte array. Since 8 is not a multiple of 3, extracting values out of this bit string may require a function like `uint32 get_bit_substr(uint8 *source_ptr, int bit_offset, int bit_length)`.  So `synch = get_bit_substr(src, 0, 7);` and `range = get_bit_substr(src, 78, 3);`  Of course the "proper" code should have these offsets and lengths either `#define` or `enum`d.